# Can timeouts be retried like messages?

Tags: nservicebus

We have a long running saga process which includes timeouts, when the timeout kicks in the first thing that happens is a call to an external data source.

We're wondering if it's appropriate to query the source directly and have the timeout hit the error queues if the source is down (or if some other issue comes up), or should we have the timeout create and send a message which is handled and from there query the source (and thus the message hits error queues if a problem arises) and then reply back to the original sender

We feel our NserviceBus code is a bit overly complex and are looking for ways to simplify it, and we're wondering if this is a good chance to do so.

```
public void Timeout(TimeoutEvent event) 
{
  bus.send(ExternalServiceCallCmd cmd)
}

public void handle(ExternalServiceCallCmd cmd) 
{
  manager.CallToExternalService();
}
```

If the call to the external service fails, the ExternalServiceCallCmd gets retried and eventually end up on error queues.

We're wondering if we can simplify like this:

```
public void Timeout(TimeoutEvent event) 
{
  manager.CallToExternalService();
}
```

and if the call to the external service fails, the TimeoutEvent would be retried and end up on error queues if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first rule of [Sagas](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/) is don't do I/O in saga handler, send commands to worker handler instead...

> Other than interacting with its own internal state, a saga should not access a database, call out to web services, or access other resources - neither directly nor indirectly by having such dependencies injected into it.

Full details are provided here: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/#accessing-databases-and-other-resources-from-a-saga

Does that answer your question?

Please feel free to contact support support@particular.net to get more details :-)